# If email not received then do X (outlook 2013 on Exchange 2010)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation, exchange

I receive notification emails daily and would like to automate an easier way to manage all of those notifications.

For example:

```
Notification 1 from asd@qwerty.com is received daily between 10pm-1am
Notification 2 from asd@qwerty.com is received daily between 12am-3am
Notification 3 from qwe@asdfg.com is received daily between 1am-4am
```

I am looking for a way to page myself at **5555551212@vzwtext.com** on my cellphone if any of these messages are not received within the defined time frame of when the email should have arrived.

I would like to basically email a page like:

```
ATTENTION Notification 2 not received within the allowed range.
```

This way I would be notified instead of having to check the email manually and see that I only received 2 of the three alerts.

Is there a way to do this in Outlook? Our exchange server is a hosted exchange server on GoDaddy if that info is needed.

Comment: Since both exchange and outlook filters are trigger based on receipt of mail, I can't think of a way to do this in outlook natively.  However based on your skills and/or available resources this wouldn't be hard to implement if you had a linux box handy, even a raspberry pi would do.. have the outlook filter hit a URL when the mail is received. have a cron running on the server that notifies you when it hasn't gotten a URL hit within the specified time.

Comment: I might just do that, brilliant!